# Display and load once

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

The problem I am encountering is that I only want the page that has been clicked to be displayed, what is happening is if I click on (a#dashboard) then later (a#stats), the content overlaps..

**How can I prevent the overlap between the contents? What I want is if I click on (a#stats), then (a#dashboard) and (a#log) must be idle.**

```
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a id = "DataOne"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home" style="font-size:25px;" aria-hidden="true"></span></a></li>
                <li><a id = "DataTwo"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt" style="font-size:25px;" aria-hidden="true"></span></a></li>
                <li><a id = "DataThree"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-stats" style="font-size:25px;" aria-hidden="true"></span></a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </nav>

<script type="text/javascript">

        $('a#dashboard').on('click',function(){
          $("#page1").load("page1.html");   
        });

        $('a#log').on('click',function(){
          $("#page2").load("page2.html"); 
        });

        $('a#stats').on('click',function(){
          $("#page3").load("page3.html"); 
        });                

</script>
```

@Lelio Faieta, this is the HTML for the three divs, and I have put the content of page1.html below.
**index.html**

```
         ......
        <script> 
            $(function(){
            $("#TopMenu").load("TopNavigationBar.html");
            }); 
        </script> 
   </head>
    <body>
          <div id="TopMenu"></div>
          <div id="page1"></div>
          <div id="page2"></div>
          <div id="page3"></div>
    </body>
```

**page1.html**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $("#dashboard").load("dashi.html"); 
</script>

<div>
      <div id="dashboard"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a common class to all the three divs and empty all of them before loading the content. So:

```
$('a#dashboard').on('click',function(){
  $('.pages').empty();
  $("#page1").load("page1.html");   
});
$('a#log').on('click',function(){
  $('.pages').empty();
  $("#page2").load("page2.html"); 
});

$('a#stats').on('click',function(){
  $('.pages').empty();
  $("#page3").load("page3.html"); 
});
```

Comment: I have tested this, but when I alternate the content is still there... Very strange.

Comment: have you given #page1 the class pages and so on for the others? Can you also show us the html of the three divs? Furthermore: why are you using delegated events? Are the divs attached later to the DOM?

Comment: I have added some more information to my first post, please take look at it.

Comment: The js that load contents to the divs is in the same Page as the divs?

Comment: Yes, that is true. That solved some other issues. Do you know how I can display only one content at time? I have used remove, but then remove does not get the content back. That is to say if I remove page1 when I go too page2, then if I go back page1 is removed... I want page1 to come back again..

Comment: I cannot see my class on the three div. Apply my solution and it is done! So div id =page1 class=pages (sorry for the formatting but I'm on mobile)

Comment: I have tried it, and it works. But I do not want the css to be empty, I want the whole html content to be totally gone when I click on another page. That is to say the page I am viewing is the only page that is running, the rest does not exist until I click on them. The reason for this is because each page is running massive amount of data, so if it runs in the background it decreases the application performance.

Comment: You are speaking about pages but I see divs. you are speaking about css but empty remove html that is included inside each div. are we talking about the same thing??

Comment: I am talking about the content inside the `page1.html`, `page2.html` and `page3.html`. The reason is because if I remove page1 and page2, then page3 runs up to 50 fps. But if I add page1 and page2, then page3 runs up to 14 fps, this is something I am trying to avoid and do not know how.